# What is the right schema for this json data coming from kafka broker to a spark streaming application in python

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

After executing this program I am recieving null values in all fields of the dataframe.If schema is the problem,Kindly me suggest me the right schema for this json format or else kindly provide me the right answer for reading this json data from kafka-topic using readStream api and print that to console.
Here is the sample json data in kafka-topic

```
        {
          "invoice_no": 154132541653705,
          "country": "United Kingdom",
          "timestamp": "2020-09-18 10:55:23",
          "type": "ORDER",
          "items": [
            {
              "SKU": "21485",
              "title": "RETROSPOT HEART HOT WATER BOTTLE",
              "unit_price": 4.95,
              "quantity": 6
            },
            {
              "SKU": "23499",
              "title": "SET 12 VINTAGE DOILY CHALK",
              "unit_price": 0.42,
              "quantity": 2
            }
          ]  
        }
```

program  without errors,I am posting main part here

```
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('retaildata').getOrCreate()
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
            jsonSchema=StructType([ \
            StructField("invoice_no",IntegerType()), \
            StructField("country",StringType()), \
            StructField("timestamp",TimestampType()), \
            StructField("type",StringType()), \
            StructField("items",StructType([StructField("SKU",IntegerType()), \
                                                    StructField("title",StringType()), \
                                                    StructField("unit_price",DoubleType()), \
                                                    StructField("quantity",IntegerType()) \
                                                     ])) \
                                  ])
        
        dfraw = spark \
          .readStream \
          .format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "18.211.252.152:9092") \
          .option("subscribe", "real-time-project") \
          .option("includeHeaders","true") \
          .load() \
          .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),jsonSchema).alias("data")).select("data.*") \
          .writeStream \
          .format("console") \
          .start() \
          .awaitTermination() \
```

Output:

```
        =================================
        I am receiving the data as
        
        Batch: 0
        -------------------------------------------
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
        |invoice_no|country|timestamp|type|items|
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
        
        -------------------------------------------
        Batch: 1
        -------------------------------------------
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
        |invoice_no|country|timestamp|type|items|
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
        |      null|   null|     null|null| null|
        |      null|   null|     null|null| null|
        |      null|   null|     null|null| null|
        |      null|   null|     null|null| null|
        +----------+-------+---------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the json string and convert as a DataFrame and then print the schema.

**Code:**

```
json_data = """
{
          "invoice_no": 154132541653705,
          "country": "United Kingdom",
          "timestamp": "2020-09-18 10:55:23",
          "type": "ORDER",
          "items": [
            {
              "SKU": "21485",
              "title": "RETROSPOT HEART HOT WATER BOTTLE",
              "unit_price": 4.95,
              "quantity": 6
            },
            {
              "SKU": "23499",
              "title": "SET 12 VINTAGE DOILY CHALK",
              "unit_price": 0.42,
              "quantity": 2
            }
          ]  
        }
"""

df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_data]))

print(df.schema.json())
print(df.schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
```

**Output:**

```
{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"country","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"invoice_no","nullable":true,"type":"long"},{"metadata":{},"name":"items","nullable":true,"type":{"containsNull":true,"elementType":{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"SKU","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"quantity","nullable":true,"type":"long"},{"metadata":{},"name":"title","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"unit_price","nullable":true,"type":"double"}],"type":"struct"},"type":"array"}},{"metadata":{},"name":"timestamp","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"type","nullable":true,"type":"string"}],"type":"struct"}


StructType(List(StructField(country,StringType,true),StructField(invoice_no,LongType,true),StructField(items,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(SKU,StringType,true),StructField(quantity,LongType,true),StructField(title,StringType,true),StructField(unit_price,DoubleType,true))),true),true),StructField(timestamp,StringType,true),StructField(type,StringType,true)))


root
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- invoice_no: long (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- SKU: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- unit_price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)

+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
|country       |invoice_no     |items                                                                                             |timestamp          |type |
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
|United Kingdom|154132541653705|[{21485, 6, RETROSPOT HEART HOT WATER BOTTLE, 4.95}, {23499, 2, SET 12 VINTAGE DOILY CHALK, 0.42}]|2020-09-18 10:55:23|ORDER|
+--------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: sample data fields order and the schema order printed in your output is totally different can you please clarify me which order I should follow to define the schema

Comment: I have executed the code by specifying the above schema that was generated in your output..it is displaying NameError: name 'List' is not defined @Shankar

Comment: Thank you..It helped me to write the schema..jsonSchema=StructType([StructField("country",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("invoice_no",LongType(),True), \
   StructField("items",ArrayType(StructType([StructField("SKU",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("quantity",LongType(),True), \
        StructField("title",StringType(),True), \
       StructField("unit_price",DoubleType(),True)]),True),True), \
   StructField("timestamp",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("type",StringType(),True)])

Comment: @PrasanthiYavanamandha the List error is basically, when you generate schema from DataFrame, it generates the schema in Scala structure, you can replace with square brackets in python.